# Dynamic images click function with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list of friends, (BOB, TINA, LISA, TERRY, MIKE) and each listed person has a picture identifying them on hover.  When you click on that person their image stays on the screen, until you click a different person. Currently I am getting the same persons picture on click regardless the name I select.

How to I create a dynamic click function in js?  When I click on a listed friend, I would like the click function to recognize which person I selected and display the image associated with that person.

Can someone please help me?

CSS

```
.BOB,.TINA,.LISA,.TERRY,.MIKE { background: url("../theme/images/blank.png") no-repeat 0 0; }

.BOB:hover { background: url("../theme/images/BOB.png") no-repeat 0 0; }
.TINA:hover { background: url("../theme/images/TINA.png") no-repeat 0 0; }
.LISA:hover { background: url("../theme/images/LISA.png") no-repeat 0 0; }
.TERRY:hover { background: url("../theme/images/TERRY.png") no-repeat 0 0; }
.MIKE:hover { background: url("../theme/images/MIKE.png") no-repeat 0 0; }

.highlight { background: url("../theme/images/BOB.png") no-repeat 0 0; display: block;}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
    $(".highlight").removeClass('highlight')
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .highlight class is using he same image always.

Can you post the html code too? It is difficult to find out what's happening without seeing your html code.

Comment: here is a link to my issue.  When you hover over one of the ratings, you will see the hover effect.  I removed the highlight code since it was problematic and useless.  I am trying to get that rating to stay when clicked.  thanks for the help. [link]http://cuuzo.com/language.html

Comment: I copied your code into jsfiddle and modified it. Here is the link to it. http://jsfiddle.net/c9Fxg/

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: It's a lot better than what I originally had.  But, only the selected should be highlighted at a time.  Right now the jsfiddle never deselects the item when another is selected.

Comment: absolutely perfect!  thank you so much.  I had been struggling with this for a few days literally.

Comment: Just updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c9Fxg/3/, as it was not showing your target image. Glad I could help :)

Comment: I noticed my links aren't working anymore, specifically class app_btn.  I think it has to do with the $("a").click(function(e){  any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: remove the e.preventDefault(); from the code, and they will start working.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `$(document).ready()` function is not closed properly.
2. Your `$("a").click()` function is not preventing the default link action (this is only a concern if you have a `href` attribute defined for the link).
3. Your `.highlight` class has a single background image, which is identical to that of your first person's background image. This is causing you to see the same background image for each one.

You can do this to fix number 3:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent link from directing to a different url
    $(this)
        .parent() // assuming the link is in the div you want to "highlight"
        .css({ // modify parent's css
            'background':
                'url(../theme/images/' + $(this).attr("class") + '.png no-repeat 0 0',
                // take class name (bob, tina, etc) and fetch image accordingly
            'display': 'block'
        });
});
```